# Eclipse class question

Tags: gloomhaven

When I'm using the consume-dark version of Concealed Dominance's bottom half, can I only teleport to hexes within line of site?  Or can I teleport to any revealed and unoccupied hex on the board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You can move to any unoccupied hex. The only restriction is that you cannot move through a closed door. Line-of-sight is not required.

From the [FAQ](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1897763/official-faq-game-no-rules-questions-please):

> What are the line-of-sight rules?
>
> Line-of-sight is necessary for all attacks (including every hex of an area attack) and all other abilities that specify a range (including looting, which technically has a range). **Any non-attack ability that does not specify a range does not require line-of-sight.**

Concealed Dominance bottom-half wording (spoiler, hover to read):

> Move to any unoccupied hex. You cannot move through a closed door.

Comment: Just got the game for Christmas a few days ago and I was unaware of that FAQ, thank you.